Pagination issue when accessing Microsoft Purview audit logs with msgraph-beta-sdk-python
When trying to retrieve Microsoft Purview audit logs using msgraph-beta-sdk-python, an AuditLogRecordCollectionResponse object containing the first page of log records and the AuditLogRecordCollectionResponse.odata_next_link (an ODATA link to the next page of logs) is returned.
However, the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-auditlogquery-list-records?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=python and the SDK functions code (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-python/blob/d84486dfe9c3de89792d8b7896671af4e510ff0a/msgraph_beta/generated/security/audit_log/queries/item/records/records_request_builder.py) don't define how to use this AuditLogRecordCollectionResponse.odata_next_link in msgraph-sdk to retrieve all the log records pages (a single query can return more than 10000 log records).
Is there a pagination feature available in msgraph-beta-sdk-python for audit log records retrieval ?
import asyncio
import datetime
import os
import time

from azure.identity.aio import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph_beta import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph_beta.generated.models.security.audit_log_query import AuditLogQuery
from msgraph_beta.generated.models.security.audit_log_record import AuditLogRecord
from msgraph_beta.generated.models.security.audit_log_record_type import AuditLogRecordType
from msgraph_beta.generated.models.security.audit_log_record_type import AuditLogRecordType
from msgraph_beta.generated.models.security.audit_log_query_status import AuditLogQueryStatus
from msgraph_beta.generated.models.security.audit_log_record_collection_response import AuditLogRecordCollectionResponse

async def getPurviewLogs(msgraph_client, queryStartDate, queryEndDate):
  request_body = AuditLogQuery(
    odata_type = "#microsoft.graph.security.auditLogQuery",
    display_name = "TestQuery",
    filter_start_date_time = queryStartDate.isoformat(),
    filter_end_date_time = queryEndDate.isoformat(),
    record_type_filters = [
      AuditLogRecordType.ExchangeAdmin,
      AuditLogRecordType.AzureActiveDirectory,
          AuditLogRecordType.AzureActiveDirectoryAccountLogon,
      ]
  )

  # Send Purview query and get query status
  queryResult = await msgraph_client.security.audit_log.queries.post(request_body)
  print(queryResult.id)
  
  # Wait during query exec
  while True:
    queryStatus = await msgraph_client.security.audit_log.queries.by_audit_log_query_id(queryResult.id).get()
    print(queryStatus.status)
    if queryStatus.status == AuditLogQueryStatus.Succeeded:
      break
    else:
      time.sleep(15)
  
  # return query results
  return await msgraph_client.security.audit_log.queries.by_audit_log_query_id(queryResult.id).records.get()

